# CKEditor: Ignoring its config.js

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have a fresh installation of CKEditor 4.7.1.  Following the tutorial on creating a plugin, I did that and then modified the config.js file to enable it.  But it won't enable.  I had posted a separate question about that, but during that, I discovered that at least part of the problem is that the config.js is being totally ignored.  For example, here's the current config.js:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
config.language = 'en';
config.uiColor = '#FFFFEE';
config.width = '100%';
config.height = 500;
config.toolbarCanCollapse = true;   
config.extraPlugins = 'timestamp';
config.allowedContent = true;
};
```

And none of those settings does anything.  But if I put them in the .replace code:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace('pageCKeditor', {
    language: 'en',
    width: '100%',
    height: '500',
    extraPlugins: 'timestamp',
    toolbarCanCollapse: true,
    uiColor: '#FFFFEE'
});

CKFinder.setupCKEditor( editor, '/includes/ckfinder/' );
```

...they work fine.  If I remove those settings from the .replace code, it will only show the default values for the editor window, thus indicating that config.js is being ignored.

I'm currently using the Full version of CKEditor, but I was having the same problem with the Standard one as well (hence why I tried a different version).

I have tried this on both my local dev machine -- a Mac running Apache 2.4, and a Windows server running IIS and the results are the same.  I tried loading the config.js on its own (after ckeditor.js) but it made no difference, so I removed it.

I've run out of things to try... any input is appreciated!

Comment: Did you clear browser cache after changing config ? can you show html code of page where you are trying to load ckeditor ?

Comment: So... I moved everything into a separate sandbox page for further testing. Everything works fine now.  But, it still doesn't work inside my application where I need the thing.

Comment: How about file permission for config.js ?

Comment: This makes no sense.  I thought okay, let's look at file permissions.  I had checked them before -- they were set to 644 (the config.js file).  For grits 'n shins, I changed them to 664.  Now it works.  Go figure.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Have you checked in the browser dev console if `config.js` is loaded properly? Maybe path to a file is incorrect and it just does not load?

Answer (score 0):

Per the OP's comment, indeed the file permissions on `config.js` *did* matter for some reason.

Fix with:

```
$ chmod 664 /path/to/ckeditor/config.js
```